# Python crashes when trying to run tkinter with progressbar

Tags: windows, python-3.x, progress-bar, ttk, crash

I'm trying to make a function that runs a ttk progressbar until a file is created. It seems that `Widget.after` is causing the APPCRASH but I don't know why. Please help!

```
def FilePgBar(title, file):
    if root:
        root.withdraw()
        boxRoot = Toplevel(master=root)
        boxRoot.withdraw()
    else:
        boxRoot = Tk()
        boxRoot.withdraw()

    boxRoot.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', denyWindowManagerClose )
    boxRoot.title(title)
    boxRoot.iconname('Dialog')
    boxRoot.geometry(rootWindowPosition)
    boxRoot.minsize(400, 100)
    pgBar = ttk.Progressbar(boxRoot, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')
    pgBar.grid(row=1, column=0)
    pgBar.pack()
    pgBar.start()
    def checkfile():
        if os.path.exists(file):
            pgBar.stop()
            pgBar.destroy()
            boxRoot.deiconify()
            boxRoot.mainloop()
            boxRoot.destroy()
            if root: root.deiconify()
        else:
            boxRoot.after(100, checkfile)

    checkfile()
```

I want to call this function from others scripts, so I'm not sure about using a class

EDIT: I edited the code. I no longer get an APPCRASH, but nothing happens when I run the program.

Answer (score 1):

Python evaluates the arguments before passing them to a function. So when it encounters

```
boxRoot.after(100, checkfile(file))
```

it evaluates `checkfile(file)` -- calling `checkfile` -- and replaces  `checkfile(file)` with the value returned by the function before calling `boxRoot.after`.

Since `checkfile(file)` has no `return` statement, `None` is returned by default. Thus

```
boxRoot.after(100, None)
```

gets called. This raises an error since the second argument to `boxRoot.after` should be a callable.

---

Instead, pass the function object `checkfile` itself:

```
def checkfile():
    if os.path.exists(file):
        pgBar.stop()
        pgBar.destroy()     
        boxRoot.destroy()
        if root: root.deiconify()
    else:
        # You need to update the progress bar            
        boxRoot.after(100, checkfile)
```

This allows the `boxRoot.after` function to call the function from *within* `boxRoot.after` instead of before `after` is called.

---

You might do something like this:

```
import os
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        self.button = tk.Button(master, text='Stop', command=self.stop)
        self.button.pack()
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(master, orient="horizontal", 
                                        length=200, mode="determinate")
        self.progress.pack()
        self.progress["value"] = 0
        self.progress["maximum"] = 100
        self.filename = '/tmp/out'
        if os.path.exists(self.filename):
            os.unlink(self.filename)
        self.checkfile()

    def checkfile(self):
        self.progress["value"] += 1
        if (not os.path.exists(self.filename) 
            and self.progress["value"] < self.progress["maximum"]):
            self.master.after(100, self.checkfile)

    def stop(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as f: pass

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps. Where is the `file` argument for checkfile?

Comment: Yes, but now it says that `checkfile()` is missing the 1 required argument, `file`!

Comment: Look again. My `def checkfile()` has no argument.

Comment: Oh! Ok, now I checked it and nothing happens when I run it!

Comment: Wait, what do I call after I define the `checkfile` function?

Comment: Nothing is happening because you need to update the progress bar. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7310511/190597 for a runnable example. One thing you'll need to decide is the maximum value, `pgBar['maximum']`. I don't know how you plan to do that if you are simply waiting for a file to exist. (i.e., how do you know when the wait is half over?)

Comment: I have looked at the link, but I still don't understand. It doesn't say anything about updating the progressbar

Comment: `self.progress["value"] = self.bytes` updates the progress bar. The progress bar is drawn based on the ratio of `self.progress['value']` and `self.progress['maximum']`.

Comment: But I'm not using a class, so I can't use `self`!

Comment: I don't know if I have said this, but I don't want to use a class because the whole reason for the function is to call it from different programs. And I am simply waiting for the file to exist. I don't need to worry about the bytes.

Comment: Still not sure what to do. Could you possibly show me how I can use the class in one program in another?