# Why are ther no white "reflections" running upon a tkinter.ttk progressbar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was creating a program with a ttk progressbar, and then I realised, that there were no white reflections on the actual bar like in this image:

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [actiprosoftware.com](http://blog.actiprosoftware.com/image.axd?picture=WindowsLiveWriter/FirstLookAnimatedProgressBarforWPFShared_13EFE/AnimatedProgressBar_27087e7d-27a1-4423-9f67-eedc95ddfe8f.gif))</sub>

`tprogressbar.style()` does not work either. Can someone help? Anything will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create downloading progress bar in ttk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310511/how-to-create-downloading-progress-bar-in-ttk)

Comment: you forgot to show your code.