# How to display the progress bar in tkinter while uploading

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on an Tkinter application in which user can upload the Excel file, and data of that excel file will be stored in database. The rows and columns is not fixed as it varies in each file.

So while the data is being uploaded in database from that file, I want to display the progress bar in the root window.

And that progress bar will only be displayed when the user uploads the file otherwise it will be hidden, and I also need to hide it after few seconds when the uploading is done.

I can create progress bar but don't know how to hide and unhide it and also don't know how to make it work in this case.

Appreciate any help regarding this

Thank you,
Anchal Bhargava

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310511/how-to-create-downloading-progress-bar-in-ttk

Comment: you have `grid_forget()`, `pack_forget()` to hide, and `grid()`, `pack()` to show again

Comment: if you do every `INSERT` to database separetally then you can change progressbar after every `INSERT`. But if you insert everything in one query then you have to do it in separated thread and you have no control - you don't know how many data is already inserted and how much to change progressbar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it almost solves my problem but I still have few problems like when I click on the upload button and select the file. After that I have displayed the progress bar but as soon as my progress bar get displayed my scroll bars become inactive.