# Ttk progress bar won't update

Tags: python, progress-bar, ttk

Here is the pare of my code that is relevant.

```
    while True:
    p = int(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=0.1))
    progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(orient=HORIZONTAL, length=screen_width, mode='determinate')
    progressbar['value'] = p
    progressbar.update_idletasks()
```

So when I run this is just spits freezes on the first value it gets from the p variable. I have tried setting VARIABLE instead of setting value like this. Please help.

Comment: You create a new Progressbar on each loop iteration. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I just want to update it. Maybe I should create it once then just change the variable. But in that case do I use variable or value. @FamousJameous

Comment: Yes, create the Progressbar once outside of the loop, pack it and then update the value in the loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7310778/3901060 for an example.

Comment: Thank you so very much for helping. Life saver. I have been working on this for 5 hours. @FamousJameous