# Stop a progress bar at Max Value Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I have created a progress bar with Tkinter :

```
self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=300, maximum=100, mode="determinate")
self.progressbar.place(x=250, y=225)
```

And i start it when i push a Button :

```
self.progressbar.start(10)
```

But i would like that it stop itself at the end of the progress bar and then doing something else (in my case open a text file) like that :

```
def LaunchButton()
    self.progressbar.start(10)
    if end of progress bar
        self.progressbar.stop()
        open text file
```

Thanks for helping !

Edit for @Saad :

My Launch button function :

```
    def launchCallBack(self):

        self.dataName = self.EditText.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
        self.dataPath = self.PathText.get(ACTIVE)
        self.dataDirectory = self.Directory.get(ACTIVE)

        print(self.dataDirectory)

        if self.dataPath == '' :
            messagebox.showinfo("error", "Please select a XML (.aird) File before launching !")
        elif '.' in self.dataName :
            messagebox.showinfo("error", "You don't have to put extension (.ctm), just put the name of your file !")
        elif self.dataName == '' :
            messagebox.showinfo("error", "Please name your Text (.ctm) File before launching")
        elif self.dataDirectory == '' :
            messagebox.showinfo("error", "Please select a directory to put your Text (.ctm) File in !")
        else :
            self.textFileCreation()
```

The function textFileCreation is your update function :

```
    def textFileCreation(self):

        self.process += 10
        self.progressbar['value'] = self.process
        if self.progressbar['value'] >= self.progressbar['maximum']:
            msg_succes = str("The file " + self.dataName + ".ctm has been created in the folder : " + self.dataDirectory)
            messagebox.showinfo("success", msg_succes)
            create_file(self.dataPath, self.dataName, self.dataDirectory)
            return
        else :
            self.after(100, self.textFileCreation())
```

Comment: You can find your answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310511/how-to-create-downloading-progress-bar-in-ttk

Comment: @Saad when i do like it is said in the post it don't change my progress bar, it don't stop at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is an example :**

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

P = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", length=300, maximum=100, mode="determinate")
P.pack()

L = Label(root, text="In Process")
L.pack()

process = 0
def update():
    global process
    process += 10
    P['value'] = process
    if P['value'] >= P['maximum']:

        L['text'] = "The Process is done!"
        # Here you can do anything when the  progress bar finishes.

        return  # This will end the after() loop
    root.after( 100, update )

update()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Also I change you function `LaunchButton()` to work accordingly. But do declare `self.process = 0` in the  `__init__` of your class

**Function**

```
def LaunchButton(self):
    self.process += 10
    self.progressbar['value'] = self.process
    if self.process >= self.progressbar['maximum']:

        # Here you can do anything when the progress bar finishes.
            # open text file

        return      # This will end the after() loop

    self.after(100, self.LaunchButton)
```

---

Comment: Thanks but i adapt my code with what you said but when i press my Launch button it execute code inside the if and then complete the progress bar i don't know why

Comment: I have edited my original post with what i did @Saad

Comment: Ok i'm fucking dumb i put `self.after(100, self.textFileCreation())` instead of `self.after(100, self.textFileCreation)` Thank you ! 2 hours for just a progress bar ...