# Tkinter progress bar not updating with variables

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am reading song progress from a phone and the duration of the postion and trying to make a stauts bar on how much is played so far

this below is added for a reference where one of the variable comes from

```
        testingdur=str(Duration[0].decode('utf-8'))
        durationString = str(testingdur.replace("Duration: ",""))
        durationString = durationString.rstrip()
        print("Duration is "+durationString)
```

here is the part thats giving me a issure with trying a making the bar step along

```
        durationStringint = int(durationString)
        Posint=int(PositionCur)
        style.theme_use('alt')
        style.configure("black.Horizontal.TProgressbar", forground='green', background='white', borderwidth=0)
        bar = Progressbar(root, length=1000, style='black.Horizontal.TProgressbar', maximum=durationStringint, variable=Posint, mode='determinate')
```

The bar does nothing it draws on screen i can see where the bar is but it does not move but i can plug number into the values manually a restart it and it works with fixed numbers

was wondering if any one could give me any advice on how to fix the issue

Comment: Wher do you update the `Progressbar['value']`?

Comment: @stovfl Do i need to have the value update even tho i am using a variable to control the bar with variable=Posint

Comment: The option *`variable=`* refers to [The Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). You are using a `int`. You have to update either `Progressbar['value'] +=` or the associated `variabel=` using  `<variable ref>.set(x)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7310778/7414759)

Comment: @stovfl Thank you thats helped a lot appreciate it

Comment: Consider to close as duplicate or write a own answer you can accept yourself to show your solution or delete the question.